# How to kick a GuildMember by ID in Discord.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I can't kick members by their ID for some reason. I can only mention them.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    usage: '%kick <mention> <reason>',
    description: 'kicks members',

    async execute(message, args, client) {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return;
        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.reply(`You do not have permission to kick`);
        let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
        if (!member) return message.reply("Please @ someone for me to kick")
        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        if (!reason) reason = "No reason Given";
        if (member.id === message.author.id) return message.reply(`You cannot kick yourself!`)

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('You have been kicked')
            .setDescription(`You have been kicked from **${message.guild.name}** for **${reason}**`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setAuthor(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setColor("#6495ED")

        if (member.kickable) {
            member.send(embed).catch(error => message.channel.send(`Couldn't Message mentioned user!`))
                .then(m => member.kick({ reason }));
            message.channel.send(`**${member.user.tag}** has been kicked!`)
        } else {
            message.reply(`Couldn't kick Mentioned user`);
        }
    }
}
```

That's the code that I have at the moment. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You might want to try using `await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0])` in case the person that's being mentioned isn't cached.

As for your question, have you tried removing the brackets and just doing `member.kick(reason)`?

Comment: No i have not tried that but made the changes you told me to do and it works great thanks!

Comment: Please post your code as a codeblock and not links to external sites